# Using java to generate WSDL with given parameters

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I am looking for some tutorials or resources that may assist me with a problem in Web Service Composition, where I need to a generate WSDL with given inputs and parameters. I want to start from scratch like java with some "element" method that can output a basic WSDL hierarchy. Thank you.

P.S. I did spend a reasonable amount of time looking for above-mentioned stuff but I do consider the probability of encountering an open source implementation from this community.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the tools provided in the [Apache CXF](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/java-to-wsdl.html) project, which allows generating WSDL from Java source and vice versa. Similar functionality is provided by [Apache Axis2](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/maven-plugins/maven-java2wsdl-plugin.html).